# How to point to the latest JDK update dynamically for downloads

Tags: java, java-7

I am writing a shell script which will wget the latest JDK 7 update from the Oracle Downloads page, is there a way to always point to the latest update so that I don't need to change my script if there's a newer update released for JDK 7

For example
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u65-b17/jdk-7u65-linux-x64.rpm

Comment: I am pretty certain oracle does not support this. You have to agree to a license before you download.

Comment: You can use specialized tools instead which use repositories that are actively maintained. For example you can use OS specific tools like apt-get (for Debian), yum (for CentOS, Redhat, Fedora). Or if you want a cross-OS solution then you can go with [SDKMAN](http://sdkman.io/) that can be used on Linux, Mac and Windows (Cygwin or Powershell). The good thing is that they are easy to use and you can use multiple versions of the same package in case of yum and SDKMAN. Another option that you have is to make use of Docker containers, in which case you can use the OpenJdk image from docker-hub.

Comment: another alternative would be to create your own registry of download links and maintain them manually based on the assumption that you read the [Critical Patch Update](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/alerts-086861.html) regularly or subscribe to their [RSS-feed](http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/rss-otn-sec.xml). Release dates are published [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release_dates.xml).